# what I am missing on this machine when I got this warning?

Tags: .net

This machine only have SDK and .Net3.5 installed. No VS2008 installed. after this warning,

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets : warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processor Architecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

I got some errors but not seen on another machine with VS2008 installed:

TestDBHelper.cs(7,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing
an assembly reference?)
TestDBHelper.cs(30,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an a
ssembly reference?)
TestDBHelper.cs(36,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an a
ssembly reference?)

any ideas? thanks,

Comment: Are you running msbuild? It looks like your code has a dependency to Visual Studio which is not installed on that machine. For a solution either install Visual Studio or remove the dependency (i.e. the unit test)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are executing a build.  Your build server should have a copy of Visual Studio installed.

In this case it's referencing some testing projects.  So, at the least you need to have MS Visual Studio Team System for Testers.  I'd recommend going ahead and installing a copy of Team Suite so that you have everything you need.

If you aren't executing a build...

Then most likely you have copied your source code to a web server.  Don't do that.  At the very least your testing project shouldn't be copied.  However, I would go on to say that NO source code should be there.  Instead compile locally and use studio to deploy / publish your project.

Answer (score 2):

Don't include your unit tests on the release you are trying to deploy.

You must have your unit tests on an assembly you are trying to distribute.  Normally you would have them in a different assembly, one that is not referenced by your production code. (ie, it is your unit tests that reference your production code, not the other way around)